# how to parse a pcap with 802.11 as protocol

Tags: pcap, dpkt

I am using dpkt to parse packets sniffed by Wireshark. 
Here is my code:

```
for ts,buf in pcap:
    try:
        eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    except(dpkt.dpkt.NeedData,dpkt.dpkt.UnpackError):
        continue
```

However, it seems that `eth` class cannot handle 802.11.

Comment: Hmm... script kiddie? And no duh, Ethernet isn't 802.11!

Answer (score 0):

As Grant Garrison so eloquently noted in comments, 802.11 is not Ethernet. You'll want to try the [`dpkt.ieee80211.IEEE80211` class of dpkt](http://dpkt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/dpkt/ieee80211.html) to parse that packet.